# Will two passing bricks in empty space induce rotation in one another?

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, scattering, tidal-effect, frame-dragging

Two identical rectangular bricks with mass $m$ pass each other anti-parallel in empty space with a constant velocity $v$. Say the smallest distance between them is $s$. Assume the bricks to be aligned with their direction of motion.

I want to find the gravitational effect they have on each other. What's the recipe to follow?

I know a framedragging effect and "normal" gravity are present. The problem is, how do I incorporate the framedragging effect?

Outside of the bricks, the energy-momentum tensor is zero. Only inside the bricks there are components of the EI-tensor. You can calculate the metric inside by means of the Einstein field equations. Say we are situated at the center of mass. How do we connect both metrics?

Will they induce a rotation in one another?

Comment: Hmm, you seem really interested in frame dragging. If you are considering idealized setups like this, then the easiest way by far to compute these effects is to use gravitoelectromagnetism, which is essentially electromagnetism with charge density replaced with mass density. No need to calculate the full metric...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism

Comment: OMG @knzhou how in the world do you know all this stuff???? -NN

Answer (score 3):

You don't need relativity to calculate this. There will be some angular momentum transfer in plain old Newtonian gravity. In the high-velocity limit each brick will experience a torque of one sign and then a torque of the opposite sign, and because the time available for rotation is short, these torques will nearly cancel out. But in the low-velocity limit you can make the bricks rotate by a large angle while passing, so the cancellation fails. The fact that the effect is optimized for low velocities tells you that it's not in any way a gravitomagnetic or frame-dragging effect.

Comment: Why doesn't the work done by the torque on one of the bricks always cancel in Newtonian gravity? In other words, let's follow one of the bricks, which will follow a hyperbolic orbit. Why doesn't the amount of time where it experiences a positive torque (say for the component perpendicular to the plane of the orbit) exactly cancel with the time it experiences a negative torque? It's not clear to me if it does or doesn't; if you know that it doesn't cancel and can explain why I think that would be a nice addition to your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm so much into the relativistic framework that I completely forgot the classical stuff going on!